# Encrypted request and response bodies and parameters even if we already have SSL / TLS?

Tags: ssl

Is there any added value in encrypted data we send in http request and response between client and server if we already have SSL / TLS ?

I get SSL/TLS already encrypts traffic across the transport layer for SSL/TLS connections but if we wanted to prevent browser users from reading request and response data, would encrypting it before it is sent add any value in preventing users being able to read it?

For instance, I could go to Network -> XHR requests -> and see what data is being transferred between client and server.

Answer (score 0):

> ... but if we wanted to prevent browser users from reading request and response data, ...

It looks like you are trying to prevent the simple reverse engineering possible with using the developer console and looking at the requests and responses. While encrypting/decrypting the data in Javascript would make this simple reverse engineering harder it will not prevent reverse engineering in general: ultimately the browser needs to have access to the information in plain so some reverse engineer could tap into the relevant parts of your Javascript based crypto to get access to the data before encryption and after decryption.

In general: if the security of your applications requires protecting against the user of the application itself, then the security design is likely wrong.